# How to fix "Library not registered" when trying to install sql server express 2014 or 2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to install sql server express 2014 (I tried 2008 also) and during the installation is always the same problem that says " Library is not registered " and so my database engine and sql browser fail to install. What can I do about it? I checked different solutions online but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Could you give us some more detail, like logs, the full error, or something?

Comment: Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.

Feature failure reason:
An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.

Error details:
§ Error installing SQL Server Browser
Library not registered.
Error code: 0x84BB0001
Visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0x08794D23%400x56F207DF&EvtType=0x08794D23%400x56F207DF to get help on troubleshooting.